# "MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +" error appears even though variable is a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to simply connect my db via mongoose onto my localhost. However, I receive this error:

```
C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\JWT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:520
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

This confuses me as the variable being passed is definitely a string. Here is my file tree:

```
JWT
|
model --- User.js
node_modules
public
routes --- .env.js, auth.js
views
index.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

//Imported routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

//Connect to db
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    {useNewUrlParser:true},
    () => console.log("connected to db")
);

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

//Route Middlewares
app.use('/api/User', authRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("All good"));
```

.env.js

```js
DB_CONNECT = "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-wu2im.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Stackoverflow said I have too much code for this question so I cannot show you the auth.js & User.js.

Comment: I think your file's name should be .env not .env.js

Comment: Tried and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: .env shoud put at root of project

Comment: You should put file .env in the same place with package.json

Comment: I put .env.js into the root and the same outcome occurred.

Comment: Do You renamed .env.js to .env ?

Comment: dotenv require a ```.env``` file not ```.env.js```

Comment: Ah, yes. Renaming it to just env and putting it in the root solved the problem. Thank you @Phong Nguyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by:

- Rename file `.env.js` to `.env`.
- Put `.env` file at root of projects.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by:

1. Rename your `.env.js` file to only `.env`
2. Put `.env` file at root directory of project.Same directory where your `package.json` file is located.
3. If this issue arrises when you deploy it such as on Heroku. On heroku it looks up for environmental variables which are declared in heroku. So just follow:
4. Go to your dashboard and in your selected app go to settings tab.
5. Go to Config vars and click reveal vars.
6. Just add your `.env` variables there in key and value pair.
7. Eg. Put `DB_CONNECT` in Key and `mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-wu2im.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority` in Value.
   That's it. You will be able to deploy your app including your .env variables.